# O formulário não envia dados ao banco

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, mysqli

Criei um formulário de cadastro de tópicos de discussão.
Tópicos de discussão estão linkados a uma categoria através de chave estrangeira.
Então, se clico em uma categoria aparece uma listagem de tópicos. O que quero é poder cadastrar um tópico ligado a uma categoria com um formulário na mesma página.

O problema ocorre quando submeto os dados que cadastro no formulário. Eles não são inseridos no banco.

Abaixo está o código:

```
<?php

include_once('conexao/conexao.php');


    if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") and ($_POST["inserir"])){


        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];
        $data_criacao = date("Y/m/d h:i:s");
        $filtro_topico = $_GET['ID'];

        $stmt = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO discussao (titulo, conteudo, id_situacao, id_topico, id_usuario) VALUES ('$titulo', '$conteudo',  1, '$filtro_topico', 3)");
        $stmt->execute();
        header('location: index.php');
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <?php
                include('templates/header.html.php');
        ?>
                <?php

                ?>

                    <div class="btn" style="margin-top: 150px; margin-left: 1020px;">
                        <a>Novo Tópico</a>
                    </div>

                        <form class="form_discussion" action="<?php echo($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 260px;">
                            <h3>Criar Tópico de Discussão</h3>
                            <label>Título:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="titulo"><br><br>
                            <label>Conteúdo:</label><br>
                                <textarea name="conteudo"></textarea><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Criar" name="inserir">
                            <input type="submit" value="Visualizar">
                            <input type="submit" value="Limpar">
                        </form>

                    <?php
                        $filtro_pagina = $_GET["ID"];
                        $query_topico = "SELECT titulo FROM topico WHERE id = " .$filtro_pagina;
                        $rs_topico = $conecta->query($query_topico);
                        while($lista_topico = $rs_topico->fetch_array()){

                    ?>

                    <div class="head_subtopics" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 260px;">
                        <h2>Tópicos de <?php echo $lista_topico['titulo']; ?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <table class="t_subtopics" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 260px;">

                    <?php
                        }
                        $filtro_topico = $lista_topico['id'];
                        $query_discussao = "SELECT DISTINCT discussao.id AS id, discussao.titulo AS titulo FROM discussao, topico WHERE discussao.id_topico = " .$filtro_pagina;
                        $rs_discussao = $conecta->query($query_discussao) or trigger_error($conecta->error."[$query_discussao]");
                        while($lista_discussao = $rs_discussao->fetch_assoc()){
                    ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 500px;">
                                    <h3><a href="discussao-respostas.php?ID=<?=$lista_discussao['id'];?>"><?php echo $lista_discussao['titulo']; ?></a></h3>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>34 respostas</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 200px;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>PDO MVC</li>
                                        <li>12:34</li>
                                        <li>por Web-user</li>

                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    <?php


                        }
                    ?>

                    </table>

            <?php
                include('templates/footer.html.php');
         ?>
</body>
```

Os erros constam na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não identifica o ID, que é o id da categoria que linkei para cadastrar um tópico.

O ID não é tratado pelo formulário. Ele é a chave primária da categoria, como a da figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele consta na url:

http://localhost/forum-ti-oficial-1/lista-discussao.php?ID=1

Comment: Aparece algum erro? Tá entrando naquele `if`?

Comment: Verifica se o ID tá vindo por GET ou POST. O segundo erro diz que tá chamando uma função a partir de uma variável que não é um objeto. Provavelmente o `prepare` tá retornando `false`

Comment: O ID não está sendo passado. Coloque-o na action do formulário (GET) ou coloque-o dentro do formulário num campo hidden (POST)

Comment: Colocar no action do formulário deu certo.
Usar um campo hidden deu conflito no fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 1):

O erro é bem descritivo, a variável $_GET['ID'] não está definida.

Solução:

```
if(isset($_GET['ID']))
    $filtro_topico = $_GET['ID'];
else 
    $filtro_topico = ID_PADRAO;//ID_PADRAO =  valor padrao
```

Além disto, a função prepare não está retornando um objeto, verifique se o erro é causado pelo problema descrito acima, se não for, verifique dentro do seu arquivo de conexão com o banco.

Comment: Não ocorreu erros, mas os dados não foram registrados no banco.